# SQL : select one column if two columns are equal, else select both

Tags: sql, select, case

I have the following SQL select problem:

I have two columns `positive threshold` and `negative threshold` (among several other columns like name, ids.... ).

- If their (absolute) value is the same (multiply by -1) then I want to select only the positive threshold as column `[threshold]`.
- If the values are different, I want to select two columns `[positiveThreshold]` and `[negativeThreshold]`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A SQL statement returns a fixed set of columns, and each row needs to have the same columns.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
select null as [threshold], positivethreshold, negativethreshold 
from table 
where negativethreshold is null 
or (positivethreshold + negativethreshold) <> 0 
union
select positivethreshold, null, null
from table 
where (positivethreshold + negativethreshold) = 0
```